# Is it true that if $f_{n}\rightarrow f$ uniformly converges then $f^{\prime}_{n}\rightarrow f^{\prime}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Let $f_{n}$ be some sequence of functions.

If $f_{n}$ uniformly converges to $f$  then is it true that  $f^{\prime}_{n}\rightarrow f^{\prime}$?

Is there an example that proves/disproves this?

Comment: No I think you need another condition on $f'_n$.

Comment: Welcome to our site!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen, Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Counterexample: $f_n = \frac1n\sin(n^2 x)$.

Comment: What does $f_{n}$ converge to?

Comment: @gbd, $f_n\to 0$ because $|f_n|\le 1/n$.

Comment: Does it converge to zero?

Comment: What is the other condition need that @GregoryGrant mentions?

Comment: @gbd, see the other answer.

Answer (score 5):

This is false in quite a strong sense. The [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) is a uniform limit of differentiable functions, but is nowhere differentiable. By the [Stone—Weierstrass Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem), any continuous function on a closed bounded interval is a uniform limit of polynomials.

Answer (score 2):

The additional condition required is that a function $g$ exists to which the $f'_n$ uniformly converge (in which case of course $g=f'$). In particular, [this PDF](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m125a/intro_analysis_ch5.pdf) proves on p. 9 that this condition suffices, but on p. 8 it shows that $f_n=\frac{x}{1+nx^2}$ is a uniformly convergent sequence whose derivatives form a convergent but not uniformly convergent counterexample.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above this not true in general. But one might still aks what a sufficient condition for "$f_n' \to f'$ uniformly" might be. If you already know that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ and $f_n'$ converges uniformly to some function say $g$, then by the fundamental theorem of calculus one indeed obtains: $g=f'$ hence $\space$$f_n' \to f'$ uniformly.